# What are red Shield items used for?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I notice often when I'm browsing the Galactic Trade Network that there are red items available called `Shielding shard`, `Shielding plate`, etc

What are these items for? The red Gel items can recharge my exosuit technologies, but the shield ones don't seem to.

The description reads

> Increased capacity energy storage unit.
>
> Promotes efficient energy storage within exosuit and starship
>   inventories.

Are they used to power up your technologies?

Comment: I'd have to start the game up to confirm but I believe they recharge the shield that goes over your health, both your exosuit and the ships.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can, at the very least, be used to charge up your ships shields after they've taken damage. You do this the same way you'd repair them with oxides (selecting them and then choosing what to repair them with... the Shielding Shard should show up in that list).

Since the shards don't stack, though, I haven't found them more efficient in terms of cargo space to store rather than just a large pile of Titanium, Zinc, or Iron. They're probably more cost-effective, though I haven't checked the math on that since cargo space is the bigger priority for me.

I haven't found any way to use them with my exosuit, but maybe I just don't have the right upgrades yet. So far I just avoid harsh environment planets since there are so many others to explore.

Comment: I've been using them mainly for fueling exosuit environment protection upgrades (i.e. radiation, cold, heat, toxic), so they can definitely be used for that.

Comment: Yeah the "correct" way to treat a lot of the unstackable, crafted fuel sources is to use them as an ephemeral way to turn common materials into fuel for things that otherwise require more expensive elements. For example while exploring a toxic planet you can craft Iron into shielding plates and use that, instead of consuming all your Zinc.